# How do I define a C++ macro for including a file

Tags: c++, macros

I need to include a file into every `.cpp` I have created as the first line in an Unreal Engine project... ***This cannot include it for EVERY cpp in the solution/project, just the ones I want it to.***

That file is:

```
#include "./../../../Public/TemplatePlatformer.h"
```

Unreal Engine states that it has to be the first include. Is there a way of macroing this so that I just define it in one place and use the macro at the top of each cpp file...*almost like an include txt file here so that the compiler thinks the header declaration is actually at the top?*

#### this:

*MyClass.cpp*

```
#include "./../../../Public/TemplatePlatformer.h"
#include "MyClass.h"

...
```

*MyClass2.cpp*

```
#include "./../../../Public/TemplatePlatformer.h"
#include "MyClass2.h"

...
```

#### would become this:

*MyClass.cpp*

```
INCLUDE_CONFIG
#include "MyClass.h"

...
```

*MyClass2.cpp*

```
INCLUDE_CONFIG
#include "MyClass2.h"

...
```

Comment: you can use [precompiled header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiled_header). it is not designed for such purpose but basically it add some headers to all your cpp files

Comment: Depending on your compiler. Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387453/include-header-files-from-command-line-gcc

Comment: @BryanChen I'm not sure what that means?

Comment: @BryanChen precompiled headers are a different feature and AFAIK does *not* guarantee that a given header is included in every translation unit

Comment: @inetknght I know it is different feature but I never know it doesn't guarantee given header is included?

Comment: What compiler and build system are you using?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2014 Community edition - The answer is i don't know

Comment: If you were using gcc, you could do this without modifying the source files at all; I don't know whether that's possible in VS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write:

```
#include INCLUDE_CONFIG
```

and in your Makefile or otherwise, invoke your compiler with `INCLUDE_CONFIG` pre-defined to the path you want; e.g. for gcc the flag would be:

```
-DINCLUDE_CONFIG="./../../../Public/TemplatePlatformer.h"
```

Comment: Do you know where i set this in visual Studio 2013?

Comment: thanks man, perfect... I stripped off the -D part and it worked great!

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 I don't use VS so can't say exactly, but there should be a section under Project Properties where you can specify conditional defines

Answer (score 2):

A simple and more flexible solution would be to create separate custom header file that contains this include and whatever else you need to be done at the start of every `.cpp`, and then include that.

So you'd create a `global.h` containing

```
#include "./../../../Public/TemplatePlatformer.h"
```

and then in every `.cpp` you'd first include that:

```
#include "global.h"
```

It's much clearer and not really more typing than a macro based solution.

Comment: You could also add `../../../Public` to your include file search path and then just `#include <TemplatePlatformer.h>` everywhere, if that's what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: You totally win this, this is much more elegant. Thank you buddy! Although, it does seem to interfere with some of the other solution.. hmm.

Comment: I ended up with: JIMMYT1988_CONFIG_INCLUDE="$(SolutionDir)Source\TemplatePlatformer\Public\TemplatePlatformer.h"