# Visual studio equivalent of -include option

Tags: visual-studio, gcc, cross-compiling

Can I have visual studio force an include of a header file on all files of a project? In other words, does it have the "-include" option like gcc?

[Include header files using command line option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387453/include-header-files-using-command-line-option)

I could not find it.

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VC++ equivalent of GCC's `-include filename` is [`/FI filename`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c5ztk84.aspx).

> This option has the same effect as specifying the file with double quotation marks
>   in an #include directive on the first line of every source file specified on the command line,
>   in the CL environment variable, or in a command file. If you use multiple /FI options,
>   files are included in the order they are processed by CL.