# C++ linking <limits> library with g++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compilation, g++

I included these libraries into my source file `main.cpp`:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <climits>
```

My entire code written in Visual Studio 2017, Windows.

I **transferred**   my code file to Linux.

When I try to compile with `g++ Item.cpp main.cpp -o main` , it gives an error for this part:

```
items[size - 1]->points = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
```

So **errors** below:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘void insert_p(Item**, int, int&)’:
main.cpp:287:33: error: ‘numeric_limits’ is not a member of ‘std’
items[size - 1]->points = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:287:48: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
items[size - 1]->points = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
                                            ^~~
```

A **correct** solution would be just replacing  `#include <climits>`
with `#include <limits>`.

Unfortunately, here is the **challenge**: Is it possible to solve this issue without changing my source code?

Is there any compiling trick to fix this?

I'm looking for a command like `g++ Item.cpp main.cpp -o main -llimits` to link `<limits>` library.

## [EDIT]:

Solved my problem with command below:

```
 g++ Item.cpp main.cpp -o main -include "limits"
```

Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3387518/7977464

And as @user4581301 said:

> It's far better to fix the code.

Thank you all.

Comment: `<limits>`, not `<climits>`

Comment: "fix" the source code, not the compiler.

Comment: "Unfortunately, here is the challenge: Is it possible to solve this issue without changing my source code?" Why?...

Comment: My caveat was eaten along with my proposed dupe so I'll recreate it here: The solutions in the duplicate are firmly in the "You probably don't want to do this, buuuuuuut..." camp. It's far better to fix the code.

Answer (score 0):

> An easy solution would be just replacing  #include <climits> with #include <limits>.

That's not an "easy" solution, it's a "correct" solution. Your source code is wrong - fix it instead of using weird workarounds.

---

> Is there any compiling trick to fix this?

You could try to redefine the token `climits` to `limits`, but it will probably not work as it will break code trying to use `climits`.

Comment: Isn't "it will probably not work as it will break code" enough? Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Yeah I looked into it and redefining the token does not affect the include, you have to have the proper header included.

Comment: To be honest, what you can do is to `#include<limits>` and then include your code (header or otherwise), but this will require you to include that before your code every time.