# How to include files in C, globally?

Tags: c

My compilation order is :
core1.c
top.c

---

core1.c contents :

```
 #include "header1.h"
 #include "header2.h"

void function1() {   
---- }

void function2() {   
---- }
```

---

header1.c contents function declarations, enums, includes :

```
 #include comdef.h    
 void function1();   
 void function2();
```

---

top.c contents :

```
 #include "header1.h"   
 #include "header2.h"   
 void main() {     
function1();  
function2();  
}
```

---

I will add more headers and more core C files into my project. Each core.c file needs the same header files. How to get this all working, without the need to put #include header1/2.h in each core1.c, core2.c etc, and include these headers only in main.c ?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? If you only include a header in `main.c` it will only be visible in that file.

Comment: Placing function declarations into `c` files makes no sense, did you mean `header1.h` instead of `header1.c`? Your headers should only contain extern function declarations, i.e. those that you want to share with the rest of your code.

Comment: Maybe this could be of interrest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387453/include-header-files-using-command-line-option

Comment: You could create a new file called let's say *headers.h*, which includes all the sources. That way when adding a new *headerXX.h* file you'll only need to change one place.

Comment: @Gerhardh - I want to simplify the file management and hence want to include all headers 1 time globally and not have to include them in each of 30+ c files.

Comment: You should only include a header where you need it. Including all headers in all C files does not make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a global header including all files

```
/* glob.h */

#ifndef GLOB_H
#define GLOB_H

#include "header1.h"   
#include "header2.h"   

#endif /* GLOB_H */
```

and in your main file

```
#include "glob.h"
```

Even if this is considered bad style, there are several projects using this approach, i.e. [gtk](https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/blob/master/gtk/gtk.h)

Comment: This doesnt work since the core.c file needs header1.h. 
I am looking to not include header1.h in core.c which it needs and still get it working.

Comment: your sentence made no sense, if glob.h include header1.h and core.c include glob.h then core.c will have header1.h datas

Comment: @Shashank, you can not do that, the compiler must know the prototype of the (`extern`) functions before using them.

Answer (score 1):

Use one header for each source file:

core1.h:

```
#ifndef _CORE1
#define _CORE1

#include comdef.h    
void function1();   
void function2();

#endif
```

core1.c:

```
 #include "core1.h"

void function1() {   
---- }

void function2() {   
---- }
```

top.c:

```
 #include "core1.h"   
 void main() {     
    function1();  
    function2();  
 }
```