# How to add a variable to each file?

Tags: c, makefile

I have this big project that contains dozens of .c file. I want to add a global variable to each file without changing the source code. Is there anyway I can do that? Maybe with a wrapper function or in MakeFile? I appreciate any help.

Sorry didn't make it clear. What I meant was for example, I want to add a variable called `int x` to each file, and then I want to use a wrapper function `__wrap_foo(int a, int x)` to replace the original function `foo(int a)`, while `foo(int a)` may or may not be used in each file. The reason I'm trying to add it as a global variable in each file is that `__wrap_foo` may not be the only wrapper function that want to use value `int x`. There might be other wrappers like `__wrap_zoo(double b, int x)` also uses and modifies the value of `x`. I hope this makes more sense.

Comment: How are the source files going to make anything useful from these global variables?

Comment: You can add the variable as an `extern` to a header file, and then declare it for real in one source file.

Comment: You are unclear, what means "add a global variable" ? we can understand that in a lot of ways

Comment: What do you mean by "add a global variable to each file"? One individually named variable in each source file, i.e. different name for each file? Make one single global variable accessable in all the files?

Comment: If you do not want to change the source files, which purpose are the added variables going to achieve?

Comment: Your question makes no sense, you wanna add a variable but you don’t wanna use it. Then don’t add it.

Comment: Please provide some example code of how you are going to use those added variables. That will probably help us to understand what exactly it is what you want.

Comment: Please convince us that what we are discussing here is not an XY problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Assume that you got an answer which explains how to achieve this. How are you going to test whether it actually works for you? How could you tell a working solution from a non-working one.

Comment: You can use shell commands in each recipe. You can use `sed` to make changes. The fact that you are having to do this points at some larger problem with your existing code.

Answer (score 0):

You can force your compiler to as-if-insert an include statement at the beginning of the source file. This way, if you add [`-include custom.h`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3387518/192373) to CFLAGS, and insert any variables, redefines, customizations to all C files that are compiled with this option.