# ChibiOS_3.0.2 migration to ChibiOS_20.3.x issues

Tags: c, makefile, embedded, chibios

I'm working on a big project on ChibiOS version 3.0.2 that compiles perfectly (let’s call it chibios3) (it is very outdated), so now I’m trying to migrate to ChibiOS version 20.3.x (let’s call it chibios20).
I took the chibios20 *chconf.h*, *halconf.h*, *mcuconf.h* and *Makefile* files from the STM32F407 Discovery demo and replaced the old configuration by them.

The old Makefile looks like this:

```
# Build global options
# NOTE: Can be overridden externally.
#

# Compiler options here.
ifeq ($(USE_OPT),)
  USE_OPT = -O2 -ggdb -fomit-frame-pointer -falign-functions=16 -std=gnu99
  USE_OPT += -DBOARD_OTG_NOVBUSSENS $(build_args)
  USE_OPT += -fsingle-precision-constant -Wdouble-promotion
endif

# C specific options here (added to USE_OPT).
ifeq ($(USE_COPT),)
  USE_COPT =
endif

# C++ specific options here (added to USE_OPT).
ifeq ($(USE_CPPOPT),)
  USE_CPPOPT = -fno-rtti
endif

# Enable this if you want the linker to remove unused code and data
ifeq ($(USE_LINK_GC),)
  USE_LINK_GC = yes
endif

# Linker extra options here.
ifeq ($(USE_LDOPT),)
  USE_LDOPT =
endif

# Enable this if you want link time optimizations (LTO)
ifeq ($(USE_LTO),)
  USE_LTO = no
endif

# If enabled, this option allows to compile the application in THUMB mode.
ifeq ($(USE_THUMB),)
  USE_THUMB = yes
endif

# Enable this if you want to see the full log while compiling.
ifeq ($(USE_VERBOSE_COMPILE),)
  USE_VERBOSE_COMPILE = yes
endif

# If enabled, this option makes the build process faster by not compiling
# modules not used in the current configuration.
ifeq ($(USE_SMART_BUILD),)
  USE_SMART_BUILD = yes
endif

#
# Build global options
##############################################################################

##############################################################################
# Architecture or project specific options
#

# Stack size to be allocated to the Cortex-M process stack. This stack is
# the stack used by the main() thread.
ifeq ($(USE_PROCESS_STACKSIZE),)
  USE_PROCESS_STACKSIZE = 0x400
endif

# Stack size to the allocated to the Cortex-M main/exceptions stack. This
# stack is used for processing interrupts and exceptions.
ifeq ($(USE_EXCEPTIONS_STACKSIZE),)
  USE_EXCEPTIONS_STACKSIZE = 0x400
endif

# Enables the use of FPU on Cortex-M4 (no, softfp, hard).
ifeq ($(USE_FPU),)
  USE_FPU = hard
endif

# Enable this if you really want to use the STM FWLib.
ifeq ($(USE_FWLIB),)
  USE_FWLIB = yes
endif

#
# Architecture or project specific options
##############################################################################

##############################################################################
# Project, sources and paths
#

# Define project name here
PROJECT = BLDC_4_ChibiOS

# Imported source files and paths
CHIBIOS = ChibiOS_3.0.2
# Startup files.
include $(CHIBIOS)/os/common/ports/ARMCMx/compilers/GCC/mk/startup_stm32f4xx.mk
# HAL-OSAL files (optional).
include $(CHIBIOS)/os/hal/hal.mk
include $(CHIBIOS)/os/hal/ports/STM32/STM32F4xx/platform.mk
include $(CHIBIOS)/os/hal/boards/ST_STM32F4_DISCOVERY/board.mk
include $(CHIBIOS)/os/hal/osal/rt/osal.mk
# RTOS files (optional).
include $(CHIBIOS)/os/rt/rt.mk
include $(CHIBIOS)/os/rt/ports/ARMCMx/compilers/GCC/mk/port_v7m.mk
# Other files (optional).
#include $(CHIBIOS)/test/rt/test.mk
include hwconf/hwconf.mk
include applications/applications.mk
include nrf/nrf.mk

# Define linker script file here
LDSCRIPT= ld_eeprom_emu.ld

# C sources that can be compiled in ARM or THUMB mode depending on the global
# setting.
CSRC = $(STARTUPSRC) \
       $(KERNSRC) \
       $(PORTSRC) \
       $(OSALSRC) \
       $(HALSRC) \
       $(PLATFORMSRC) \
       $(BOARDSRC) \
       $(CHIBIOS)/os/hal/lib/streams/chprintf.c \
       $(CHIBIOS)/os/various/syscalls.c \
       main.c \
       comm_usb_serial.c \
       irq_handlers.c \
       buffer.c \
       comm_usb.c \
       crc.c \
       digital_filter.c \
       ledpwm.c \
       mcpwm.c \
       servo_dec.c \
       utils.c \
       servo.c \
       servo_simple.c \
       packet.c \
       terminal.c \
       conf_general.c \
       eeprom.c \
       commands.c \
       timeout.c \
       comm_can.c \
       ws2811.c \
       led_external.c \
       encoder.c \
       flash_helper.c \
       mc_interface.c \
       mcpwm_foc.c \
       $(HWSRC) \
       $(APPSRC) \
       $(NRFSRC)

# C++ sources that can be compiled in ARM or THUMB mode depending on the global
# setting.
CPPSRC =

# C sources to be compiled in ARM mode regardless of the global setting.
# NOTE: Mixing ARM and THUMB mode enables the -mthumb-interwork compiler
#       option that results in lower performance and larger code size.
ACSRC =

# C++ sources to be compiled in ARM mode regardless of the global setting.
# NOTE: Mixing ARM and THUMB mode enables the -mthumb-interwork compiler
#       option that results in lower performance and larger code size.
ACPPSRC =

# C sources to be compiled in THUMB mode regardless of the global setting.
# NOTE: Mixing ARM and THUMB mode enables the -mthumb-interwork compiler
#       option that results in lower performance and larger code size.
TCSRC =

# C sources to be compiled in THUMB mode regardless of the global setting.
# NOTE: Mixing ARM and THUMB mode enables the -mthumb-interwork compiler
#       option that results in lower performance and larger code size.
TCPPSRC =

# List ASM source files here
ASMSRC = $(STARTUPASM) $(PORTASM) $(OSALASM)

INCDIR = $(STARTUPINC) $(KERNINC) $(PORTINC) $(OSALINC) \
         $(HALINC) $(PLATFORMINC) $(BOARDINC) $(TESTINC) \
         $(CHIBIOS)/os/various \
         $(CHIBIOS)/os/hal/lib/streams \
         mcconf \
         appconf \
         $(HWINC) \
         $(APPINC) \
         $(NRFINC)

#
# Project, sources and paths
##############################################################################

##############################################################################
# Compiler settings
#

MCU  = cortex-m4

#TRGT = arm-elf-
TRGT = arm-none-eabi-
CC   = $(TRGT)gcc
CPPC = $(TRGT)g++
# Enable loading with g++ only if you need C++ runtime support.
# NOTE: You can use C++ even without C++ support if you are careful. C++
#       runtime support makes code size explode.
LD   = $(TRGT)gcc
#LD   = $(TRGT)g++
CP   = $(TRGT)objcopy
AS   = $(TRGT)gcc -x assembler-with-cpp
AR   = $(TRGT)ar
OD   = $(TRGT)objdump
SZ   = $(TRGT)size
HEX  = $(CP) -O ihex
BIN  = $(CP) -O binary

# ARM-specific options here
AOPT =

# THUMB-specific options here
TOPT = -mthumb -DTHUMB

# Define C warning options here
CWARN = -Wall -Wextra -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes

# Define C++ warning options here
CPPWARN = -Wall -Wextra -Wundef

#
# Compiler settings
##############################################################################

##############################################################################
# Start of user section
#

# List all user C define here, like -D_DEBUG=1
UDEFS =

# Define ASM defines here
UADEFS =

# List all user directories here
UINCDIR =

# List the user directory to look for the libraries here
ULIBDIR =

# List all user libraries here
ULIBS = -lm

#
# End of user defines
##############################################################################

ifeq ($(USE_FWLIB),yes)
  include $(CHIBIOS)/ext/stdperiph_stm32f4/stm32lib.mk
  CSRC += $(STM32SRC)
  INCDIR += $(STM32INC)
  USE_OPT += -DUSE_STDPERIPH_DRIVER
endif

build/$(PROJECT).bin: build/$(PROJECT).elf
    $(BIN) build/$(PROJECT).elf build/$(PROJECT).bin

# Program
upload: build/$(PROJECT).bin
    #qstlink2 --cli --erase --write build/$(PROJECT).bin
    #openocd -f interface/stlink-v2.cfg -c "set WORKAREASIZE 0x2000" -f target/stm32f4x_stlink.cfg -c "program build/$(PROJECT).elf verify reset" # Older openocd
    openocd -f board/stm32f4discovery.cfg -c "reset_config trst_only combined" -c "program build/$(PROJECT).elf verify reset exit" # For openocd 0.9

#program with olimex arm-usb-tiny-h and jtag-swd adapter board. needs openocd>=0.9
upload-olimex: build/$(PROJECT).bin
    openocd -f interface/ftdi/olimex-arm-usb-tiny-h.cfg -f interface/ftdi/olimex-arm-jtag-swd.cfg -c "set WORKAREASIZE 0x2000" -f target/stm32f4x.cfg -c "program build/$(PROJECT).elf verify reset"

debug-start:
    openocd -f stm32-bv_openocd.cfg

RULESPATH = $(CHIBIOS)/os/common/ports/ARMCMx/compilers/GCC
include $(RULESPATH)/rules.mk

Demo Makefile looks like(i added the sources and the include dirs):

# Build global options
# NOTE: Can be overridden externally.
#

# Compiler options here.
ifeq ($(USE_OPT),)
  #USE_OPT = -O2 -ggdb -fomit-frame-pointer -falign-functions=16
  USE_OPT = -O2 -ggdb -fomit-frame-pointer -falign-functions=16 -std=gnu99
  USE_OPT += -DBOARD_OTG_NOVBUSSENS $(build_args)
  USE_OPT += -fsingle-precision-constant -Wdouble-promotion
endif

# C specific options here (added to USE_OPT).
ifeq ($(USE_COPT),)
  USE_COPT =
endif

# C++ specific options here (added to USE_OPT).
ifeq ($(USE_CPPOPT),)
  USE_CPPOPT = -fno-rtti
endif

# Enable this if you want the linker to remove unused code and data.
ifeq ($(USE_LINK_GC),)
  USE_LINK_GC = yes
endif

# Linker extra options here.
ifeq ($(USE_LDOPT),)
  USE_LDOPT =
endif

# Enable this if you want link time optimizations (LTO).
ifeq ($(USE_LTO),)
  USE_LTO = yes
endif

# Enable this if you want to see the full log while compiling.
ifeq ($(USE_VERBOSE_COMPILE),)
  USE_VERBOSE_COMPILE = no
endif

# If enabled, this option makes the build process faster by not compiling
# modules not used in the current configuration.
ifeq ($(USE_SMART_BUILD),)
  USE_SMART_BUILD = yes
endif

#
# Build global options
##############################################################################

##############################################################################
# Architecture or project specific options
#

# Stack size to be allocated to the Cortex-M process stack. This stack is
# the stack used by the main() thread.
ifeq ($(USE_PROCESS_STACKSIZE),)
  USE_PROCESS_STACKSIZE = 0x400
endif

# Stack size to the allocated to the Cortex-M main/exceptions stack. This
# stack is used for processing interrupts and exceptions.
ifeq ($(USE_EXCEPTIONS_STACKSIZE),)
  USE_EXCEPTIONS_STACKSIZE = 0x400
endif

# Enables the use of FPU (no, softfp, hard).
ifeq ($(USE_FPU),)
  USE_FPU = no
endif

# FPU-related options.
ifeq ($(USE_FPU_OPT),)
  USE_FPU_OPT = -mfloat-abi=$(USE_FPU) -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16
endif

#
# Architecture or project specific options
##############################################################################

##############################################################################
# Project, target, sources and paths
#

# Define project name here
PROJECT = ch

# Target settings.
MCU  = cortex-m4

# Imported source files and paths.
CHIBIOS  := ./ChibiOS_20.3.x
CONFDIR  := ./cfg
BUILDDIR := ./build
DEPDIR   := ./.dep

# Licensing files.
include $(CHIBIOS)/os/license/license.mk
# Startup files.
include $(CHIBIOS)/os/common/startup/ARMCMx/compilers/GCC/mk/startup_stm32f4xx.mk
# HAL-OSAL files (optional).
include $(CHIBIOS)/os/hal/hal.mk
include $(CHIBIOS)/os/hal/ports/STM32/STM32F4xx/platform.mk
include $(CHIBIOS)/os/hal/boards/ST_STM32F4_DISCOVERY/board.mk
include $(CHIBIOS)/os/hal/osal/rt-nil/osal.mk
# RTOS files (optional).
include $(CHIBIOS)/os/rt/rt.mk
include $(CHIBIOS)/os/common/ports/ARMCMx/compilers/GCC/mk/port_v7m.mk
# Auto-build files in ./source recursively.
include $(CHIBIOS)/tools/mk/autobuild.mk
# Other files (optional).
include $(CHIBIOS)/test/lib/test.mk
include $(CHIBIOS)/test/rt/rt_test.mk
include $(CHIBIOS)/test/oslib/oslib_test.mk

#My changes
include hwconf/hwconf.mk
include applications/applications.mk
include nrf/nrf.mk

# Define linker script file here
LDSCRIPT= $(STARTUPLD)/STM32F407xG.ld

# C sources that can be compiled in ARM or THUMB mode depending on the global
# setting.
CSRC = $(ALLCSRC) \
       $(TESTSRC) \
       main.c \
       comm_usb_serial.c \
       buffer.c \
       comm_usb.c \
       crc.c \
       digital_filter.c \
       ledpwm.c \
       mcpwm.c \
       servo_dec.c \
       utils.c \
       servo.c \
       servo_simple.c \
       packet.c \
       terminal.c \
       conf_general.c \
       eeprom.c \
       commands.c \
       timeout.c \
       comm_can.c \
       ws2811.c \
       led_external.c \
       encoder.c \
       flash_helper.c \
       mc_interface.c \
       mcpwm_foc.c \
       $(HWSRC) \
       $(APPSRC) \
       $(NRFSRC)

# C++ sources that can be compiled in ARM or THUMB mode depending on the global
# setting.
CPPSRC = $(ALLCPPSRC)

# List ASM source files here.
ASMSRC = $(ALLASMSRC)

# List ASM with preprocessor source files here.
ASMXSRC = $(ALLXASMSRC)

# Inclusion directories.
INCDIR = $(CONFDIR) $(ALLINC) $(TESTINC) \
         mcconf \
         appconf \
         $(HWINC) \
         $(APPINC) \
         $(NRFINC)

# THUMB-specific options here
TOPT = -mthumb -DTHUMB

# Define C warning options here.
CWARN = -Wall -Wextra -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes

# Define C++ warning options here.
CPPWARN = -Wall -Wextra -Wundef

#
# Project, target, sources and paths
##############################################################################

##############################################################################
# Start of user section
#

# List all user C define here, like -D_DEBUG=1
UDEFS =

# Define ASM defines here
UADEFS =

# List all user directories here
UINCDIR =

# List the user directory to look for the libraries here
ULIBDIR =

# List all user libraries here
ULIBS = -lm

#
# End of user section
##############################################################################

##############################################################################
# Common rules
#

RULESPATH = $(CHIBIOS)/os/common/startup/ARMCMx/compilers/GCC/mk
include $(RULESPATH)/arm-none-eabi.mk
include $(RULESPATH)/rules.mk

#
# Common rules
##############################################################################

##############################################################################
# Custom rules
#

#
# Custom rules
##############################################################################
```

Now I run the command `make`, and I got errors that tells that this project can’t understand the basic syntax, like *uint8_t*, *uint16_t*, etc. Even the word "true" is not defined.

The error looks like this:

```
 2910 |   __I  uint8_t   RESERVED2[3];
      |        ^~~~~~~
./ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/startup/ARMCMx/compilers/GCC/../../../../../../../ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/startup/ARMCMx/devices/ADUCM36x/../../../../../../../ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/ext/ADI/ADUCM36x/../../../../../../ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/ext/ADI/ADUCM36x/ADuCM360.h:2911:8: error: unknown type name 'uint8_t'
 2911 |   __IO uint8_t   I2CMTX;                    /*!< Master Transmit Data                  */
      |        ^~~~~~~
./ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/startup/ARMCMx/compilers/GCC/../../../../../../../ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/startup/ARMCMx/devices/ADUCM36x/../../../../../../../ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/ext/ADI/ADUCM36x/../../../../../../ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/ext/ADI/ADUCM36x/ADuCM360.h:2912:8: error: unknown type name 'uint8_t'
 2912 |   __I  uint8_t   RESERVED3[3];
      |        ^~~~~~~
./ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/startup/ARMCMx/compilers/GCC/../../../../../../../ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/startup/ARMCMx/devices/ADUCM36x/../../../../../../../ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/ext/ADI/ADUCM36x/../../../../../../ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/ext/ADI/ADUCM36x/ADuCM360.h:2913:8: error: unknown type name 'uint16_t'
 2913 |   __IO uint16_t  I2CMRXCNT;                 /*!< Master Receive Data Count             */
      |        ^~~~~~~~
./ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/startup/ARMCMx/compilers/GCC/../../../../../../../ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/startup/ARMCMx/devices/ADUCM36x/../../../../../../../ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/ext/ADI/ADUCM36x/../../../../../../ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/ext/ADI/ADUCM36x/ADuCM360.h:2914:8: error: unknown type name 'uint16_t'
 2914 |   __I  uint16_t  RESERVED4;
      |        ^~~~~~~~
./ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/startup/ARMCMx/compilers/GCC/../../../../../../../ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/startup/ARMCMx/devices/ADUCM36x/../../../../../../../ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/ext/ADI/ADUCM36x/../../../../../../ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/ext/ADI/ADUCM36x/ADuCM360.h:2915:8: error: unknown type name 'uint16_t'
 2915 |   __IO uint16_t  I2CMCRXCNT;                /*!< Master Current Receive Data Count     */
      |        ^~~~~~~~
./ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/startup/ARMCMx/compilers/GCC/../../../../../../../ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/startup/ARMCMx/devices/ADUCM36x/../../../../../../../ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/ext/ADI/ADUCM36x/../../../../../../ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/ext/ADI/ADUCM36x/ADuCM360.h:2916:8: error: unknown type name 'uint16_t'
 2916 |   __I  uint16_t  RESERVED5;
      |        ^~~~~~~~
./ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/startup/ARMCMx/compilers/GCC/../../../../../../../ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/startup/ARMCMx/devices/ADUCM36x/../../../../../../../ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/ext/ADI/ADUCM36x/../../../../../../ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/ext/ADI/ADUCM36x/ADuCM360.h:2917:8: error: unknown type name 'uint8_t'
 2917 |   __IO uint8_t   I2CADR0;                   /*!< 1st Master Address Byte               */
      |        ^~~~~~~
./ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/startup/ARMCMx/compilers/GCC/../../../../../../../ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/startup/ARMCMx/devices/ADUCM36x/../../../../../../../ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/ext/ADI/ADUCM36x/../../../../../../ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/ext/ADI/ADUCM36x/ADuCM360.h:2918:8: error: unknown type name 'uint8_t'
 2918 |   __I  uint8_t   RESERVED6[3];
      |        ^~~~~~~
./ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/startup/ARMCMx/compilers/GCC/../../../../../../../ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/startup/ARMCMx/devices/ADUCM36x/../../../../../../../ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/ext/ADI/ADUCM36x/../../../../../../ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/ext/ADI/ADUCM36x/ADuCM360.h:2919:8: error: unknown type name 'uint8_t'
 2919 |   __IO uint8_t   I2CADR1;                   /*!< 2nd Master Address Byte               */
      |        ^~~~~~~
./ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/startup/ARMCMx/compilers/GCC/../../../../../../../ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/startup/ARMCMx/devices/ADUCM36x/../../../../../../../ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/ext/ADI/ADUCM36x/../../../../../../ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/ext/ADI/ADUCM36x/ADuCM360.h:2920:8: error: unknown type name 'uint8_t'
 2920 |   __I  uint8_t   RESERVED7[7];
      |        ^~~~~~~
./ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/startup/ARMCMx/compilers/GCC/../../../../../../../ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/startup/ARMCMx/devices/ADUCM36x/../../../../../../../ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/ext/ADI/ADUCM36x/../../../../../../ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/ext/ADI/ADUCM36x/ADuCM360.h:2921:8: error: unknown type name 'uint16_t'
 2921 |   __IO uint16_t  I2CDIV;                    /*!< Serial clock period divisor register  */
      |        ^~~~~~~~
./ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/startup/ARMCMx/compilers/GCC/../../../../../../../ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/startup/ARMCMx/devices/ADUCM36x/../../../../../../../ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/ext/ADI/ADUCM36x/../../../../../../ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/ext/ADI/ADUCM36x/ADuCM360.h:2922:8: error: unknown type name 'uint16_t'
 2922 |   __I  uint16_t  RESERVED8;
      |        ^~~~~~~~
./ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/startup/ARMCMx/compilers/GCC/../../../../../../../ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/startup/ARMCMx/devices/ADUCM36x/../../../../../../../ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/ext/ADI/ADUCM36x/../../../../../../ChibiOS_20.3.x/os/common/ext/ADI/ADUCM36x/ADuCM360.h:2923:8: error: unknown type name 'uint16_t'


14:00:20 Build Failed. 811 errors, 3 warnings. (took 5s.161ms)
```

Comment: I'd try adding a force include of stdbool.h and stdint.h in the USE_OPT flag: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387453